# How should i load the read only data on server startup?

Tags: jsf

How should i load the standard read only data such as labels, select options, other boolean value, etc on server start up with using hibernate. How should i avoid the database call during render the page on each user request for pulling above read only information from database. I am using JSF with hibernate and tomcat 7. How can I implement the solution for such scenario?

Comment: Can you share how you currently do it?

Comment: As of now on each user request every thing pulling from database again and again. I created entity class and dao layer. Dao layer is responsible for making an sql connection and pulling the data. In init method of bean class i am requesting for the data which will use in rendering the page.

Comment: If it's application scoped data, just put bean holding the data in application scope instead of request scope?

Comment: So i need to create a bean to put in application scoped and load the data from application bean and use in every pages. Am i true?